# How do I create a qt app in nim

Tags: linux, qt5, qtgui, nim-lang

I'm looking to use nim in an upcoming project, but I'm not sure where to start. I've worked on a fair few webapps over the last two years and I'm pretty good with python. I'm also very good with Linux.

Now I want to make a GUI app for linux, maybe using qt. I looked up qt how tos but they use c++ or python mostly and qt creator. How can I tie nim to qt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use qt as the UI for your Linux app and then build the logical backend of your app in Nim, export it as a C library and call it from the user interface layer. That's what I did for Seohtracker, the UI is done in ObjectiveC for OSX or IOS, but the backend is [implemented in Nim](https://github.com/Araq/seohtracker-logic) exported through a thin C API.

In theory you can grab that logic module, slap a qt UI layer and have a Linux client. The [Nim backend integration guide](http://nim-lang.org/docs/backends.html) explains how you can do this trickery of mixing and calling different languages together.

Comment: This is great. So if I'm getting this right, I should be able to make one back end in nim and create UIs in other languages/frameworks that call into my back end. That sounds neat!

Comment: @Ananth yes, in theory you could even use Nim to generate js and run your app in a web browser

Answer (score 0):

While there is no Qt binding for Nim yet, you can use Qml: http://forum.nim-lang.org/t/692